# getting cannot find symbol error for System.out.println() in all program trying to compile

Tags: java

I tried to print hello world program but i am getting error saying cannot find symbol for System.out.println("hello world")

```
class Pra {
  public static void main(String[] arg){
      System.out.println("Hello Wolrd");
 }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7PU2.png)

> pra.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
> System.out.println("Hello World");

Comment: Show us the code for your ENTIRE program.

Comment: class Pra{
 
  public static void main(String[] arg){

 System.out.println("Hello Wolrd");

 }

}

Comment: for error message please go through image description

Comment: Your program compiles and runs for me.  (As I expected.)  So either this is not the exact program that you are trying to run, or you have a broken Java installation.  I'm calling this "not reproducible".

Comment: I am still getting same error . how to identify broken Java installation and resolve it .need help

Comment: Agreed.  Code compiles and runs just fine for me.  Uninstall and reinstall Java?

Comment: have uninstalled and again installed the latest java version 15.0.1 , But still getting the same error . i dont know whats wrong ..

Comment: Is there another computer you can test against?  I can't think of anything else for you to try.

Comment: I have made a tutorial on how to setup java and write hello world program, so it is exactly what you need 

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXy8DQl3058NyJO3HcAJZvYNMK7JrpV6k